# Binding to android project when no jar can be created

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I would like to use an android project in xamarin for example this one: https://github.com/jaydeepw/poly-picker

This project is written in java and has resources and activities.
As far as I understand it is not possible to compile such a project into a jar and then to create a binding library.
Is this correct?

What options do exist to use such a project, apart from porting the source code?

Comment: It doesn't seem like a massive project, you could convert the code to c# for one

Comment: @InitLipton yes, I already outlined this possibility in the last sentence of my question :) are there any other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, only you can binding Java libraries, not apps.

You can read this post:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)/